# Need to apply correlation matrix on the sql query on spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sample dataset which contains the data related to employees of an organisation. Please find the schema below for the dataset.

The problem which I am trying to solve here is, What is the most important criteria for an employee to stick to an organization using correlation matrix.
I am trying to solve this in sql query in spark/scala.

```
Schema of the Dataset
 |-- satisfaction_level: float 
 |-- last_evaluation: float 
 |-- number_project: integer 
 |-- average_monthly_hours: integer 
 |-- time_spend_company: integer 
 |-- work_accident: integer 
 |-- left: integer 
 |-- promotion_last_5years: integer 
 |-- department: string 
 |-- salary: string
```

I tried with this below query but it is not yielding me any results, as per my understanding and analysis of the data I can prove that **when the satisfaction_level is going down the employees tend to leave the organisation**.

```
val correlationVal = employeesDF.stat.corr("satisfaction_level","left")
```

I am finding issues in writing the sql query to solve the above mentioned problems, can anybody help me with this? What is the correct way to apply correlation matrix for this problem?

Note: If there is any better/simpler approach to solve this problem using Spark, then please share me your inputs.

Comment: what is the result for the code mentioned by you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal code which works for me:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val schema = StructType( Array(
      StructField("col1", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("col2", FloatType, true)
    ))

val rdd = sc.parallelize( Seq(Row(1, 1.34.toFloat), Row(2, 2.02.toFloat), Row(3, 3.4.toFloat), Row(4, 4.2.toFloat)))
val dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
dataFrame.stat.corr("col1","col2")
```

The result is `0.9914` which is almost near to 1 indicating columns are correlated.